# Custom XML-element name for base class field in serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, inheritance, xml-serialization

How can I change XML-element name for field inherited from base class while doing serialization?

For example I have next base class:

```
public class One
{
    public int OneField;
}
```

Serialization code:

```
static void Main()
{
    One test = new One { OneField = 1 };
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (One));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Output.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, test);
    writer.Close();
}
```

I get what I need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<One xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OneField>1</OneField>
</One>
```

Now I have created new class inherited from `A` with additional field and custom XML element name for it:

```
public class Two : One
{
    [XmlElement("SecondField")]
    public int TwoField;
}
```

Serialization code:

```
static void Main()
{
    Two test = new Two { OneField = 1, TwoField = 2 };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Two));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Output.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, test);
    writer.Close();
}
```

As a result I get next output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Two xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OneField>1</OneField>
  <SecondField>2</SecondField>
</Two>
```

The problem is that I want to change `OneField` in this output to `FirstField` without touching base class code (because I will use it too and the names must be original). How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Two : One
{
    private static XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOverrides;
    public static XmlAttributeOverrides XmlOverrides
    {
        get
        {
            if (xmlOverrides == null)
            {
                xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
                var attr = new XmlAttributes();
                attr.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("FirstField"));
                xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(One), "OneField", attr);
            }
            return xmlOverrides;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("SecondField")]
    public string TwoField;

}
```

And your serializer init is a lot easier:

```
 var xmls = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Two), Two.XmlOverrides);
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I need. But is there any way to embed this overrides to class declaration so it will works automatically anytime when objects are serialized?

Comment: Unfortunately not to my knowledge. You can try exposing the `XmlAttributeOverrides` object as a static field on your target class to make it a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:  Override the fields in the subclass and mark the overriden field with whatever name you need.  For example,

```
class One
{
    public int OneField { get; set; }
}

class Two : One
{
    [XmlElement("FirstField")]
    public new int OneField
    {
       get { return base.OneField; }
       set { base.OneField = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this the serializer threw an exception:{"There was an error reflecting type '<T>'"}

Comment: @Jay: Darn, forgot to check the code before posting.  Remembered doing this a while ago, but must have gotten something wrong.  That solution you posted above is slick