# How to serialize a class member to xml based on its type

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, abstract-class

**Problem:** I have some serializable classes like these:

```
public abstract class Person {}
public class Student : Person {}
public class Teacher : Person {}

[Serializable()]
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Student))]
[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(Teacher))]
public class Room
{   
    [XmlElementAttribute(??)]
    public Person[] persons;
}
```

Suppose i have an object like this:

```
Room r = new Room();
r.persons= new Person[]{new Student(), new Teacher()};
```

**My Result:** When I serialize it, it will be something like this:

```
<Room>
    <Person />
    <Person />
</Room>
```

**What I need:** What I need is this, but I don't know

```
<Room>
    <Student/>
    <Teacher/>
</Room>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, here are two of them:

1. the class `Room` must implement interface 'IXmlSerializable'. this will allow you to make your serialisation more flexible ([How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly)).
2. Or you can use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to override serialisation. ([Custom XML-element name for base class field in serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258404/3107178))

Comment: Thanks. I found the idea in your link.
 `public class Room
 {
        [XmlElement("Student", typeof(Student))]
        [XmlElement("Teacher", typeof(Teacher))]
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution but with one more middle layer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication8 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Room r = new Room();
            r.Persons = new List<Person>();
            r.Persons.Add(new Student() { StudentID = "001" });
            r.Persons.Add(new Teacher() { Name = "James" });

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Room));
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, r);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Person { }

    public class Student : Person {
        public String StudentID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher : Person {
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Room {
        [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Student)),
        XmlArrayItem(typeof(Teacher))]
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before and the output is good. but there is an extra `<Persons>` element. this is what I need: <Room>
    <Student>
      <StudentID>001</StudentID>
    </Student>
    <Teacher>
      <Name>James</Name>
    </Teacher>
</Room>